# Publishing map service with QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, map-service

I am new to QGIS, and I am from Esri ArcGIS background
I would like to know how to create a server on my machine that I can use to publish map services for online use.
I just downloaded QGIS 2.8 from this link and installed it on my machine, I created a project that contains a Shapefile layer, and saved it as .qgs file.
I don’t know how to publish this file as map service that can be accessed by URL.
Does anyone know how can I install the QGIS publishing engine (QGIS Server) on my machine and configure it to share map services?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the documentation for QGIS Server
https://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/QGIS_Server_Tutorial

Some other helpful links

http://live.osgeo.org/en/quickstart/qgis_mapserver_quickstart.html
http://anitagraser.com/2012/04/06/qgis-server-on-windows7-step-by-step/